# Excel formula that returns sum based on categorical and date data from 2 columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset in excel that looks like this:

```
Supplier    Date          QTY
A           03/02/2018    10
A           05/01/2018    15
A           08/06/2018    30
B           02/01/2018    20
B           04/01/2018    50
B           08/01/2018    40
B           08/15/2018    50
B           10/01/2018    60
C           03/09/2018    25
C           04/08/2018    25
C           05/20/2018    25
```

And I want to make a spreadsheet that allows the user to enter start and end dates and the Supplier name and be able to see a total quantity of items received in that time period from that supplier.

I've tried using a combination of VLOOKUP and SUM, but I've only been able to get the first result of the quantity associated with that supplier to return. I understand that this is the nature of VLOOKUP--to only return one value. I'm pretty new to Excel so I just don't really even know which function(s) would be best to use in this scenario.

Example Output:

```
Enter Supplier: "B"
Enter Start Date: "03/01/2018"
Enter End Date: "09/01/2018"

Items Received: 140
```

Comment: You want to look into `COUNTIFS` and `SUMPRODUCT`

Comment: This is precisely what the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) is designed to do.  Using your example, it would be something like this: `=SUMIFS(<QTYColumn>,<SupplierColumn>,"B",<DateColumn>,">=3/1/2018",<DateColumn>,"<=9/1/2018")`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A12=F1)*(B2:B12>=F2)*(B2:B12<=F3)*(C2:C12))
```

**Result:**

[image]